# Wp7 push notification to launch my app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

As far as I know, Ios and Android gcm are able to open an application when a push notification event arrives.
For wp7, I only find samples on how to update tiles or display a message. But I need to display a bitmap in fullscreen.
Is there a way to open my app when I send a push notification ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To be honest, I hope you can't. Why would you want to be able to launch apps remotely? I would hate it! The way I know it works on iOS is that when you receive a push notification and you unlock your phone you go to the app immediately. If you decide not to act directly you have to launch the app manually.

From that point of view, I don't think it's possible and if it is, I doubt it will make your app very popular.

Comment: User must have the choice. Just need a button to tell stop push notifications for my app until next manual launch or a turn on/off push notifications inside system to keep control.

Comment: iOS does not allow arbitrary execution of an application on push notification, it requires interaction with the user in the same way that WP7 does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no way you can launch anything** via a push notification on Windows Phone. Raw, toast and tile are the only acceptable types, none of which is able to invoke code execution outside the pre-defined boundaries (e.g. launch the app when the toast is tapped).

Since you are displaying an image, your best bet would be focusing on the [tile updating mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202970%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Remember, however, that there are no guarantees that the user will see the tile (unless pinned), or keep it on the home screen permanently.

Answer (score 1):

If you send a Toast notification using the Notification mechanism, then tapping on the Toast will launch the application, you can then specify a page to navigate to within your application.

Take a look at the following for more information :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202967(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I don't want a toast, I need to display a bitmap in fullscreen without any touch event and close my app after a predefined duration.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: But is it possible to use push notifications to send datas when my app is running like Android gcm ?

Comment: You can use Raw Notifications for this purpose : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202977(v=vs.92).aspx